# Finding an average of a loop from a different method?

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, methods, average

I am in the middle of an exercise on arrays and I am currently stuck on one of the variations in which

- I have to use an Array (no arraylists) to gather user input with a
  max number of 100 inputs and the inputs must stop if a negative
  number is inserted.
- The program then prints each value input by the user on a separate
  line with the "Above", "Below", or "EqualTo" relating to the average
  of the inputs.

**Issue :-** I am currently stuck in how I am supposed to get the value of the inputs from the load method into the correct spots on the print method. The program will compile but will only return an average1 equal to zero. Any help is appreciated, I just can't use an arraylist

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScoreSetNumber3
{
 private int[] scores;
 private static final int SIZE= 100;
 private double average1;
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 public ScoreSetNumber3()
 {
  scores = new int[SIZE];
 }

 public void load()
 {
 System.out.println("Please enter scores");

 double sum = 0;

 for( int used = 0; used < scores.length; used++)
 {
    scores[used] = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(scores[used] >= 0)
   {  
   sum += scores[used];
   }

   else
   {
   System.out.println("End of Inputs");

    double average1 = sum / used; 
    System.out.println("Average value of array elements is" + " " + average1);
    break;
    }
  }
 }

 public double getAverage()
 {
    return average1;
 }

 public void print()
  {  

      for(int used=0; used < scores.length; used++)
        {
             if(scores[used] > getAverage())
        {
          System.out.println(scores[used] + " Above");
        }

        else if(scores[used] == getAverage())
        {
          System.out.println(scores[used] + " EqualTo");
        }

        else
        {
          if(scores[used] < 0)
          {
           break; 
          }
          System.out.println(scores[used] + " Below");
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are **not** saving the average to the global variable `average1` but to a local variable. That is why `average1` returned by `getAverage()` equal to zero.

Change the below line in `load()` method from

```
double average1 = sum / used;
```

to

```
average1 = sum / used;
```